# Distinc on trunc date (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with `createdAt` and `id` field. And I'm trying to get every 1st day of every month

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON ("date") DATE_TRUNC('month', "createdAt") AS "date", "createdAt"
    FROM
        "walletBalances"
    WHERE
        "walletId" = 1
    ORDER BY
        "date" DESC) t
ORDER BY
    "createdAt" DESC;
```

This query transform this

```
+----------+------------------------------+
| walletId | createdAt                    |
+----------+------------------------------+
| 1        | 2019-11-20 20:00:00.00000+03 |
+----------+------------------------------+
| 1        | 2019-11-21 20:00:00.00000+03 |
+----------+------------------------------+
| 1        | 2019-10-17 20:00:00.00000+03 |
+----------+------------------------------+
| 1        | 2019-10-14 20:00:00.00000+03 |
+----------+------------------------------+
```

To this

```
+----------+------------------------------+------------------------+
| walletId | createdAt                    | date                   |
+----------+------------------------------+------------------------+
| 1        | 2019-11-21 20:00:00.00000+03 | 2019-11-01 00:00:00+03 |
+----------+------------------------------+------------------------+
| 1        | 2019-10-17 20:00:00.00000+03 | 2019-10-01 00:00:00+03 |
+----------+------------------------------+------------------------+
```

The problem is that `DISTINCT ON ("date") DATE_TRUNC('month', "createdAt") AS "date"` use `2019-10-17 20:00:00.00000+03` as the unique field (?) but not much early date `2019-10-14 20:00:00.00000+03` that presented in the table.

How I can get such result? So `DISTINCT ON` will always use the smallest date.

```
+----------+------------------------------+------------------------+
| walletId | createdAt                    | date                   |
+----------+------------------------------+------------------------+
| 1        | 2019-11-21 20:00:00.00000+03 | 2019-11-01 00:00:00+03 |
+----------+------------------------------+------------------------+
| 1        | 2019-10-14 20:00:00.00000+03 | 2019-10-01 00:00:00+03 |
+----------+------------------------------+------------------------+
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the logic backwards:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (DATE_TRUNC('month', "createdAt"))
       DATE_TRUNC('month', "createdAt") AS "date", "createdAt"
FROM "walletBalances"
WHERE "walletId" = 1
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

You can use a subquery if you really want the results in descending order.

Or you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', "createdAt") AS "date", MIN("createdAt") as first_date_in_month
FROM "walletBalances"
WHERE "walletId" = 1
GROUP BY "date"
ORDER BY date DES;
```

Comment: the second answer is worked but how to select other fields? if I add a `createdAt` field into `SELECT` sql will return `column "walletBalances.createdAt" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: ok, seems like I can use `JOIN` to select other fields, thanks